# JSF2 - Stop multiple validation errors for the same field (ie there can be only one)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Given this snippet in a facelet:

```
    <h:messages layout="table"></h:messages>
    <br /><br />
    First Name: 
    <h:inputText styleClass="inputText" id="firstName" validatorMessage="#{msg['error.userEdit.firstName']}">
        <f:validateRequired></f:validateRequired>
        <f:validateLength maximum="50"></f:validateLength>
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$"></f:validateRegex>
    </h:inputText>
```

When validation runs on the form, I get between 0-3 of the same message printed out in my  depending on how many of the validation rules failed for the field.  How do you restrict it to a single message per field?

For clarity, my error message is all encompassing of the 3 errors and says "First Name is required, cannot exceed 50 characters, and must be alpha characters only.", so this is why I only want it printing one time.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to write your own custom `Validator` instead of using those three provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<h:message>` instead of `<h:messages>`. This way only the first one will be displayed.

```
<h:message for="firstName" />
```

Yes, this approach would require you to specify a `<h:message>` for every individual input field instead of a single `<h:messages>`. There's no other standard way.

Comment: I had tried that, and once you said it should work, I started digging in farther.  Apparently when running in developer mode in Apache MyFaces-2, it puts the other two messages at the bottom of the page.  Once I turned off developer mode, it worked as you said it should.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that are the development stage messages. They will only show messages which are not shown "the usual way". They may hint the developer about unforeseen errors.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to just set this field by one regex

You need Use this

```
< f:validateRegex pattern="[A-Za-z]{0,50}" >
```